# "Ordinal 132 not found in SSLEAY32.dll" after installation of TeeChart 2013

Tags: delphi, teechart

After installation of the new TeeChart 2013 Pro to Delphi XE2 I am hitting the error shown in the title when I try to load or create a new project. After clicking OK Delphi runs fine. Sometimes the error box comes back when a new project is loaded.

I deactivated all non-Delphi components (did not uninstall, though), no change.

The same occured on the second PC with Delphi that I have access to. Of course, both machines are configured very similarly. Both of them have Win7, one 32-bit, the other one 64-bit. Delphi 7 does not show the error.

Steema, the manufacturer of TeeChart, does no know of this issue. Did anybody else see this behavior, and is there a solution or workaround?

Comment: Smells more like Indy to me. That's an SSL DLL.

Comment: @TLama SVN came in with XE. And yes, that's quite plausible actually. It certainly runs over SSL.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what Steema goes to **DLL hell** with replacing OpenSSL binaries shipped with RAD Studio (used by either Indy components or Subversion add-in).

Comment: @David: SVN is hot - I disabled the svn integration package, and now the message is gone. I think I can live with that situation since I use TortoiseSVN instead of the built-in SVN. It would be interesting, though, to understand why this issue occured.

Comment: TeeChart installation does nothing with either subversion integration nor Indy packages. It doesn't even use the mentioned DLL at all.